# How to join mutiple row and single row from different table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to join user, resume and resume_experience in one row but

One user have multiple `resume_experience`  and only have one `resume`

How can I join them and compare it by job_position and job_category?

Or this is impossible and I have to write another sql query for it?

```
SELECT * FROM resume r
INNER JOIN job j ON j.job_category = r.resume_category
LEFT JOIN user u ON r.resume_user = u.user_id  
LEFT JOIN resume_experience re ON re.resume_experience_position = j.job_position 
WHERE j.job_id = 1 GROUP BY r.resume_user
```

Above is my sql query but the `LEFT JOIN resume_experience` is not working.

```
resume
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| resume_id | resume_user | resume_category |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
|         1 |           1 |               1 |
|         2 |           2 |               1 |
|         3 |           3 |               1 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+

job
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  job_id | job_employer | job_position | job_category |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|       1 |            1 |            1 |            1 |
|       2 |            2 |            1 |            1 |
|       3 |            3 |            2 |            1 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+

resume_experience
+-----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
|  resume_experience_id | resume_experience_position | resume_experience_user |
+-----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
|                     1 |                          1 |                      1 |     
|                     2 |                          2 |                      1 |  
+-----------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+

user
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |     david |
|       2 |    kelvin |
|       3 |       bob |
+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: can share what's inside job_category table?

Comment: You have user_id column in user that has a different column name resume_user in resume, etc. This way you create confusion for yourself and introduce errors in writing queries.

Comment: @metal There is no `job_category` table. `job_category` is just a column in `job`.

Comment: @metal job_category is static one. For example: 0 = White Collar, 1 = Blue Collar

Comment: Can you show the result you're trying to get? I suspect what you need is `GROUP_CONCAT()`, but it's not clear.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Comment: "compare it by job_position and job_category" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the result on a single row for each user  you could use group_concat for the column with multiple values

```
SELECT resume.* , group_concat(re.resume_experience_position)
FROM resume r
INNER JOIN job j ON j.job_category = r.resume_category
LEFT JOIN user u ON r.resume_user = u.user_id  
LEFT JOIN resume_experience re ON re.resume_experience_position = j.job_position 
WHERE j.job_id = 1 
GROUP BY r.resume_user
```

Left join is for not macthing values.
For reduce rows  you need  ana aggregation function and group  by  ..